# Angular-Browserify + ui.router - States produces "Uncaught object"

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript

I have a project that needs better structure than most of the angular-browserify seeders specifically for small-projects out there. Is it possible to have an index which requires all routes? Such as [this (which is on RequireJS)](https://github.com/plmph/web/blob/master/public/app/index.js)

My project is using gulp.js and coffeescript

My project structure

```
- assets/
    - bower_components/
    - coffee/
        - directives/
            - login.coffee
            - registration.coffee
        - services/
            - auth.coffee
            - user.coffee
        - utils/
            - states/
                    - auth.coffee
                    - dashboard.coffee
                    - index.coffee
                    - main.coffee
                    - modules.coffee
                    - otherwise.coffee
        - app.coffee
        - main.coffee
```

**assets/main.coffee**

```
bootstrap = require '../bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap'
$ = require '../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery'

$(document).ready ->
    angular = require '../bower_components/angular/angular'
    angular_ui_router = require '../bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router'
    lumina = require './app'
    services = require './services/modules'
    directives = require './directives/modules'
    states = require './utils/states/modules'

    return
```

**assets/app.coffee**

```
app = angular.module 'app', ['ui.router']

module.exports = app
```

**assets/utils/states/modules.coffee**

```
otherwise = require './otherwise'
dashboard = require './dashboard'
auth = require './auth'
main = require './main'
index = require './index'
```

**assets/utils/states/auth.coffee**

```
app = require '../../app'

app.config [($stateProvider) ->
    auth = 
        name: 'main.auth'
        abstract: true
        resolve:
            auth: AuthSrvc ->
                return AuthSrvc.check()

    $stateProvider.state(auth);
]
```

**/assets/utils/states/dashboard.coffee**

```
app = require '../../app'

app.config [($stateProvider) ->

]
```

**/assets/utils/states/index.coffee**

```
app = require '../../app'

app.config [($stateProvider) ->
    index =
        name: 'main.index'
        url: '/'
        resolve:
            auth: AuthSrvc ->
                return AuthSrvc.check()

    $stateProvider.state(index)
]
```

**/assets/utils/states/main.coffee**

```
app = require '../../app'

app.config [($stateProvider) ->
    main =
        name: 'main'
        abstract: true
        templateUrl: '../views/main/template.html'

    $stateProvider.state(main);
]
```

**/assets/utils/states/otherwise.coffee**

```
app = require '../../app'


app.config [($urlRouterProvider) ->
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise '/'
]
```

When I try to load my states file, I receive an "Uncaught object" error. And I have no idea why.

Comment: Do you have a stack trace a bit more complete than an error message ?

Comment: I tried try-catch on the angular.module() on app.coffee  but nothing seems to change. Any ideas or tips?

Comment: Doesn't your console give you some kind of stack traces ?

Comment: Oh, you meant this? http://imgur.com/iNUQaF7

Comment: Yeah, though using a non-minified version could help with debugging :)

Comment: It automatically minifies due to gulp.js. Let me rid of it for the mean time. Anyway, all the lines in the stack traces are all from AngularJS :)

Comment: Yeah, these kind of errors usually arise when a module is missing.

Comment: Seems to be a problem with the $stateProvider.. hmm. When I tried to comment almost all states except the main, removed everything in it, and put this code in the main:

app = require '../../app'

app.config [ ->
]

no error occured

Comment: Seems to be a problem with the injection. If you'll notice: app.config([($stateProvider) -> . Will test, be back.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the spam. I think it gives the "Uncaught" thingy when I try calling services. Any idea why? I think this is the problem.

Comment: Problem solved. Dependencies not being injected.

Comment: Haha yeah, I guessed because I made the same mistake not long ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to dependencies not being injected. This is how I formed my config / state / whatever.

```
app.config [($stateProvider) ->
    auth = 
        name: 'main.auth'
        abstract: true
        resolve:
            auth: AuthSrvc ->
                return AuthSrvc.check()

    $stateProvider.state(auth);
]
```

Notice line 1, wherein I annotate the dependencies for minification. I did not annotate the dependency likewise: `app.config [`**`'$stateProvider'`**`, ($stateProvider) ->`.